# Make sure only 1 cell has an active state in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` in which I want only want 1 cell to be active. With active I mean: the last cell that has been clicked (or the very first cell when to collection view lays out). When a user clicks a non-active cell, I want to reset the old active cell to a non-active state. I am having trouble doing this. This is because `visibleCells`, a property of collection view, only returns the cells on screen but not the cells in memory. This is my current way to locate an active cell and reset the state to non active.

This scenario can happen, causing multiple active cells: A user scroll slightly down so that the current active cell is not visible anymore, taps on a random cell and scroll up. The problem is that the old active cell stays in memory, although it is not visible: `cellForItemAt(_:)` does not gets called for that cell. Bad news is that visibleCells also do not find the old active cell. How can I find it? The function `willDisplay cell` also does not work.

An example project can be cloned directly into xCode: https://github.com/Jasperav/CollectionViewActiveIndex.

This is the code in the example project:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: CollectionView!
    static var activeIndex = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.go()
    }
}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: MyButton!

}

class CollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func go() {
        delegate = self
        dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 500
    }

    internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        if indexPath.row == ViewController.activeIndex {
            cell.button.setTitle("active", for: .normal)
        } else {
            cell.button.setTitle("not active", for: .normal)
        }
        cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }

    @objc private func touchUpInside(_ sender: UIButton){
        let hitPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self)
        guard let indexPath = indexPathForItem(at: hitPoint), let cell = cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Cell else { return }

        // This is the problem. It does not finds the current active cell
        // if it is just out of bounds. Because it is in memory, cellForItemAt: does not gets called
        if let oldCell = (visibleCells as! [Cell]).first(where: { $0.button.titleLabel!.text == "active" }) {
            oldCell.button.setTitle("not active", for: .normal)
        }

        cell.button.setTitle("active", for: .normal)

        ViewController.activeIndex = indexPath.row
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recover from this glitch you can try in `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.button.tag = indexPath.row
```

when the button is clicked set

```
ViewController.activeIndex = sender.tag
self.reloadData()
```

Comment: I have no idea why I didnt think about reloading the data for the last 2 hours -_- thank you :D. To save some memory, I added an else statement to my existing code:         if let oldCell = (visibleCells as! [Cell]).first(where: { $0.button.titleLabel!.text == "active" }) {
            oldCell.button.setTitle("not active", for: .normal)
        } else {
            reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(row: ViewController.activeIndex, section: 0)])
        }

Comment: Yes it's good to save memory actually the glitch makes me aggressive to achieve even with consuming memory :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isSelected` property of the `UIColectionViewCell`. You can set an active layout to your cell if it is selected. The selection mechanism is implemented by default in the `UIColectionViewCell`. If you want to select/activate more than one cell you can set the property `allowsMultipleSelection` to true.

Basically this approach will look like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: CollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.go()
    }

    func activeIndex()->Int?{
        if let selectedItems = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
            if selectedItems.count > 0{
                return selectedItems[0].row
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool{
        didSet{
            if self.isSelected
            {
                myLabel.text = "active"
            }
            else
            {
                myLabel.text = "not active"
            }
        }
    }
}


class CollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func go() {
        delegate = self
        dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 500
    }

    internal func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I can have multiple cells with the property set to true. I have an example project that can be cloned in 5 seconds (see my question), maybe you can see if you get it to work :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with the suggested approach implemented.